# Unlocking Samsung RV520 Phoenix SecureCore Tiano BIOS from being locked by questionable security company

Tags: hard-drive, bios

A very good friend of mine made the mistake of signing up for an online security software company. When she was unhappy with their service she requested a refund. They told her that she needed to send $1000.00 to them. When she refused they shut her laptop computer down.

What I have found is that the hard drive has a password on it and I can’t make the BIOS recognize any other drives. I think the only way to salvage her computer is to reset the BIOS or replace it.

Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with this type of situation? Thanks in advance for any ideas.